# Rescue player from going wrong direction in dungeon game

Tags: ruby, rescue

I'm trying to use rescue to save my dungeon game from an error if the player types in a direction that isn't available in the game and will instead repeat their location back to them again and ask where to go.  Here's the relevant code:

```
def go(direction)
    puts "You go " + direction.to_s
    @player.location = find_room_in_direction(direction)
    show_current_description
end

def show_current_description
    puts find_room_in_dungeon(@player.location).full_description
    puts "Where will you go?"
    answer = gets.chomp.downcase
        if answer == "exit"
            puts "You somehow teleported out of the cave. Good work."
            exit
        else
            answer = answer.to_sym
            begin
                go(answer)
            rescue
                puts "You can't go that way!"
                show_current_description
            end 
        end
end
```

this is the result I get from typing in an unacceptable answer:

> You find yourself in a large cavernous cave. To the west is a small aperture
>
> Where will you go?
>
> east
>
> You go east
>
> You can't go that way!
>   You can't go that way!
>   You can't go that way!
>
> dungeon.rb:40:in `show_current_description': undefined method`full_description' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
>       from dungeon.rb:52:in `rescue in show_current_description'
>       from dungeon.rb:48:in`show_current_description'
>       from dungeon.rb:20:in `start'
>       from dungeon.rb:89:in`'

Here's all the code: [My full Dungeon Code](https://github.com/heylittlehouse/Ruby-Dungeon/blob/master/code)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please make sure you have as much relevant code as possible in the question itself. In this question, the relevant code is the `go` method; we should not have to go off-site for it.

Comment: Thanks @Amadan. I would have included it if I had known it WAS the relevant code in the first place. Shows how much I know! Still new to this!

Answer (score 3):

Your rescue is catching the wrong thing. You perform the `go` operation, it assigns the next room; but it is `nil`. The thing that then fails is looking up the description on a `nil`. Instead of catching the error of failed room description lookup, you need to prevent the assignment if the room does not exist.

EDIT: Something like this might be okay.

```
def show_current_description
  loop do
    puts find_room_in_dungeon(@player.location).full_description

    puts "Where will you go?"
    answer = gets.chomp.downcase

    if answer == "exit"
      puts "You somehow teleported out of the cave. Good work."
      exit
    end

    next_location = find_room_in_direction(direction)
    if next_location
      puts "You go " + direction
      @player.location = next_location
      break
    else
      puts "You can't go that way!"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi @Amadan thanks for your response.  I've tried fixing my rescue based on your suggestions but I just get more error messages. quite honestly this is my first use of rescue so I'm still trying to figure out how it works. Can you be a little more descriptive and/or show me what would be a functioning way to rescue the go method?